# C++ cURL How to download a file from FTP and save it locally with file Modification Date on Server

Tags: c++, linux, curl, ftp

I want to check if file:
ftp://xxx/config.ini
has newer Modification Date, than same file on local system for example:
/home/john/config.ini
If yes, download it and save locally with ftp://xxx/config.ini Last Modification date.
How to do that?
(I know how to check Mod Date, I just need to know how to write it with remote Modification Date)

Comment: Write file, then use `utime(2)` to change its modification date.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this today. Thought there is a way directly in libcurl, cause from command line U can do this with --remote parameter